# Cannot find Linear Layout in a Splash Screen - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, android-layout

My splash screen stretches badly when I run my app , so I tried a solution on one of the questions here to manually adjust dither and purge like so

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        myOptions.inDither = true;
        myOptions.inScaled = false;
        myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        myOptions.inDither = false;
        myOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap preparedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplication()
                .getResources(), R.drawable.bg, myOptions);
        Drawable background = new BitmapDrawable(preparedBitmap);
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main))
                .setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

Instead of putting the image of the splash which causes bad stretching I am setting the background and configuring options. 
My xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/layout_main">
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried Clean+rebuild+refresh but still I get a NullPointerException at

```
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main))
                .setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

It cannot find the linear layout.  Any ideas? Help!

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you ensured that `Drawable background` isn't returning a `null` object? Try splitting that `findViewById` statement into separate steps. `LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R...);` then `ll.setBackgroundDrawable(..)`. Insert `null` checks in between to see _exactly_ where the NPE is generated.

Comment: Its at LinearLayout ll - Basically findViewById returns null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding some dummy content like imageview with src = @null to the layout. Otherwise the layout did not inflate. After that I did what I was doing and voila. Moral: To inflate a layout that you want to find programmatically - add some dummy content and not just the layout (I dont know what the official docs say, but this is what I ve found in my case)